# Weight Initialization for Mask RCNN without using pretrained weights from Imagenet / COCO

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
# define the model

model = MaskRCNN(mode='training', model_dir='./', config=config)

# load weights (mscoco) and exclude the output layers

model.load_weights('mask_rcnn_coco.h5', by_name=True, exclude=["mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc",  "mrcnn_bbox", "mrcnn_mask"])
# train weights (output layers or 'heads')

model.train(train_set, test_set, learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE, epochs=2, layers='heads')
```

I have certain medical images containing fibroids. 
I wish to apply instance segmentation or object detection. 
I may have to use mask Rcnn for instance segmentation and object detection. Is it possible to design the network from scratch instead of using transfer learning? 
What I mean here is random initialization of weights for my data, instead of using weights derived from imagenet data or coco data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line,instead of training a model starting from pre-trained COCO weights like this

`python my_model.py train --dataset=/path/dataset --weights=coco`

execute the following line.

`python my_model.py train --dataset=/path/dataset`

And to start training from the first layer execute the following code.

`model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val,learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE,epochs=10,         layers='all')`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just run the training without doing the model.load_weights() line?  It seems to be running fine for me when I do that.  I assume that runs it with randomized initial weights.  It didn't result in quite as good results as starting with coco does, but I'm sure that's expected behavior for some datasets.